# Electrical circuit in series with a light bulb to be controlled

Tags: home-automation

Is it possible to control(turn on/off, dim) a light bulb from a circuit that is in series with the light bulb?

Basically to replace the on/off switch with such a circuit.

If yes, do you know if and where this approach is used?

Thanks

Comment: If you are asking about mains power, if you have to ask, you SHOULD not! This is dangerous, and illegal in most places without an appropriate licence.

Comment: Ok, let's say I'm not talking about mains, let's say 12 or 24 volts

Comment: This has nothing explicitly to do with the Raspberry Pi and would be more appropriate to our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can control a light with a relay, transistor or FET depending on voltage/current See https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits

For AC a relay is the only viable option (although SSR can provide a non-mechanical altenative).

You can control brightness using PWM although this depends on the nature of the load.